# How can I use context "this" at {{}} vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have this code

```html
<div
      v-for="i of 10"
      :key="i"
      class="frame"
      :background-image="`url(${require('../assets/images/slides/' +
        this.$assetsResolution + //where $assetsResolution is a Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution
        '/' +
        i +
        '.jpg')})`"
    ></div>
```

but I cant use $assetsResolution without data field that just set another variable with  $assetsResolution value. So why... Or there is another way...

Comment: Try just `$assetsResolution` (without `this.`)

Comment: it is better create background image url with computed property or method IMO

Comment: Can I ask plz, why its working without context "this" before variable...

Comment: @Serio In the template, you do not use this. `this` is only used in the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vue, I would put a logic as complicated as yours in the `script`, not in the template.  You could e. g. put your whole expression in a function in the computed section, and then just call this function in the template.